# Error Reporting

Tags: updates, password, apport

I am relatively new to Ubuntu (have installed 12.1 on my desktop).  There are certain software updates done by Ubuntu automatically without asking for password recently.  Every now and then it now prompts me that "some errors have occurred" and asking me to **REPORT** by entering my password.

Is this a normal behavior or some malicious software at work ?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is no malicious software, this is just part of the Linux-development and bugfix network. You enter your password in order to garant the reporting tool access to the information needed to create a ticket.

This is basically the idea of Linux: nothing is allowed until you admit it.
Windows: everything is allowed except you forbid it. ;-)

This principle is the reason for Linux based OS to be more secure than others. But keep in mind, even if security relevant-fixes are usually fixed within a day after reporting, and there is no use for a firewall software unless you run a server: it is possible though to create a virus for linux OS and you should keep phishing-attacks in mind while browsing.

Comment: Please note that entering your password to send Apport crash information is **only** required in a minority of cases, like reporting bugs in the kernel. Most crashes don't require any special authentication, and can even be reported by non-administrators.